# Android Studio Dinamically add a new Section

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm a beginner in Android development and I'm stucked in a way to dinamically add or remove a new Section.

The image below shows the way I want to do it. If I press the + button then a new item is created and I can insert the info about the item. If i press the - button then it will delete the item.

[image: Sections]

I don't want to make the items to be fixed. I need the user to insert as many items as they want to.

Comment: you probably need ListView, just google Android ListView tutorial. You can add and remove items in your ListView adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dynamic views I suggest `RecyclerView`, which is more flexible than `ListView` and provide basic animations by default (proper calls on adapter - `notifyItemInserted`, `notifyItemRemoved`).

[Here](http://blog.lovelyhq.com/creating-lists-with-recyclerview-in-android/) is an example.